# does @return cast the return type?

Tags: zend-framework

```
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat
 */
protected function _loadNodes($parentNode = null, $recursionLevel = 0, $storeId = 0, $onlyActive = true){
    ....
    $nodes = array();
    return $nodes;

}
```

will this return an object or an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No @return doesn't cast a return type. It will return the array only. In above of the function we have comment where we gave the information about the function like what is the argument type which we need to pass on time of function call, what is return type( so comment for this function is wrong ).